# Do Florida woods cockroaches (aka Palmetto bugs) commonly sell for ~US$80/kg in China?

Tags: entomology, china, alternative-medicine

According to [this article on Yahoo news](http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/oddnews/woman-who-cares-for-100-000-cockroaches-in-home--%E2%80%98these-are-all-my-children%E2%80%99-163242043.html),  citing a similar [South China Morning Post article](http://www.scmp.com/news/china/article/1530812/meet-chinas-cockroach-lady-pharmacist-turned-insect-enthusiast-touts), Yuan Meixia bought her initial stock of 20kg of cockroaches for around US$1600:

> Yuan, a pharmacy employee, was inspired to raise roaches after seeing
>   a China Central Television program that aired last year. “I saw people
>   raise this kind of cockroach in Anhui,” she said. “They said it can be
>   food and also can be medicine…So I took tens of thousands of yuan to
>   learn [how to breed them] for a week and spent more than 10,000 yuan
>   ($1,600) to buy 20 kg (44 lbs) of live cockroaches.”

The article later explains how she drowns, dries, and sells the cockroaches for nutritional and folk medicine use, apparently making a nice profit:

> Yuan sells the roaches after they are drowned in vats of water and
>   then drying in the sun. ”Those dried ones can be sold at 300 yuan to
>   400 yuan ($48-$64) per jin (1.1 lb).

The specific type of cockroach mentioned in the article is the Palmetto bug.  Wikipedia calls these the [Florida woods cockroach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida_woods_cockroach) and differentiates them from some other species.

If you ask Google "400 yuan in dollars" the answer (as of June 13, 2014) is $64.40, so apparently the literal currency conversion is correct. The SCMP article has numerically compatible conversions into HK$.

But there could always have been a decimal point error somewhere.

I have doubts that one can routinely sell cockroaches for such a high price.  For instance, there is no well-known international trade in cockroaches, yet these prices are much higher than prices for other internationally traded bulk foodstuffs such as fruits, meat, etc.

It could be a temporary or localized bubble.  Another possibility is a scam promoted through smaller local media, to attract unsophisticated investors to copycat, that happened to be picked up unaware by more reputable news media as a curiosity.

Do Florida woods cockroaches commonly sell for ~US$80/kg in China?

Comment: There's another alternative. The market may be legitimate, but small - too small (or too low margin) to warrant setting up international operations.

Comment: The best price I could find online for *Eurycotis floridana* was [$0.80/nymph](http://www.roachcrossing.com/climbingpetroaches.htm), but that's for a small batch of only 25. Assuming that price, to  get $80/kg would mean that each one weighs about 10g, which I find reasonable. For a discount on bulk orders, it would mean that either the average weight was a bit different, or the price went up for other considerations(shipping, etc). I'd say this sound plausible. A kilogram of roaches is a lot of roaches.